# Accessing Innerhtml of Web Controls in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to Access a section present in a Repeater Control by passing `this` in a function

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptReminder" runat="server">
    <section style="display:<%# CheckReminder(this,DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.DueDate")) %>">
<img src="rem.jpg" onclick="SendReminder()">
</section>

</asp:Repeater>
```

in C#

```
 public string CheckReminder(object oThis,Object oDueDate)
    {
     DateTime DueDate=Convert.ToDateTime(oDueDate);
     if(DueDate>=DateTime.Now.Date)
     {
      return "";
     }
     System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl element=(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)oThis;
     element.InnerHtml = "<span>Reminder Already Sent Today!</span>";
    return "";
    }
```

But its throwing  Invalid Cast exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.Reminder_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.
```

How can I get/set innerHtml of the section in CheckReminder

Answer (score 0):

In `<%# %>` you are writing C# code, so `this` refers to the current page (unlike what you expect in JavaScript, in which `this` refers to the current element).

I would go for something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptReminder" runat="server">
    <section>
      <span style="display:<%#   CheckReminder(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.DueDate")) %>">Reminder Already Sent Today!</span>
      <img src="rem.jpg" onclick="SendReminder()" style="display:<%#   CheckReminder2(DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.DueDate")) %>">
    </section>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and:

```
public string CheckReminder(Object oDueDate)
{
 DateTime DueDate=Convert.ToDateTime(oDueDate);
 if(DueDate>=DateTime.Now.Date)
 {
  return "inline";
 }
}

public string CheckReminder2(Object oDueDate)
{
 DateTime DueDate=Convert.ToDateTime(oDueDate);
 if(DueDate>=DateTime.Now.Date)
 {
  return "none";
 }
}
```

Just note that `CheckReminder` and `CheckReminder2` return opposite values. Please check them based on the required logic.

Comment: My aim is use Same Section for both i.e Displaying SendReminder Button as well as Text.....based on the Condition.that is why i'm looking for a way to access innerHtml of the section

Comment: but you are just hiding the img or span....can't i change the inner HTML of section...instead of hiding it?

Comment: You might be able to achieve that by using `ItemDataBound` event of your repeater. Use `e.Item` to find controls inside the current item and change their contents as needed. Please note that, in order to be able to use `FindControls`, you need to use server controls (such as Label and Image) instead of html tags (such as span and img).